# How to find which exact configuration aws cli is using?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have an EC2 instance created in my AWS account. It is using Amazon Linux 2 AMI in Canada region.
After creating the instance I didn't do anything to configure AWS CLI.

When I run some basic aws cli commands (e.g. `aws s3 ls`) it works.
But I'm not able to find which configuration this cli is using.

As per the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html) (Refer section: Configuration settings and precedence), there are several places where aws cli can look for configuration and there is an order in which they are looked up.

I know I can manually go and check each of the place to see if anything is set there.

But I want to know which exact configuration aws cli is using if I'm running without any config specific option.

Is there an option/switch/flag that I can pass to aws cli to find out which exact configuration(place of config) the cli is referring to or using? e.g. it may return system variable or configuration file or aws creds file etc.

AWS CLI version in my env:

```
aws-cli/1.16.300 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.13.36
```

Comment: Since it is a new Amazon EC2 and you didn't configure anything, it is most probably receiving the credentials via an IAM Role that is assigned to the instance.

Comment: Correct. That's why I want a way to confirm it.

Comment: Well, you could remove the IAM Role and then see whether it still works.

Comment: That's a heuristic/trial-error method, I was looking for a better way to get it straight. The answer from @Marcin is useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `--debug` flag would be helpful:

```
aws s3 ls --debug 2>&1 | grep "botocore.credentials"
```

Which gives:

```
2021-07-11 07:03:24,669 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Skipping environment variable credential check because profile name was explicitly set.
2021-07-11 07:03:24,672 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2021-07-11 07:03:24,672 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2021-07-11 07:03:24,672 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2021-07-11 07:03:24,672 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2021-07-11 07:03:24,673 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
```

Grep pattern matches for AWS CLI version:

```
aws-cli/1.16.300 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.14.186-146.268.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.13.36
```

Comment: Perfect. This is insightful. did some minor changes in your answer.